# <PATH_TO_SUMO>/bin/netedit: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: ecs_SetReportErrorFunction

Tags: sumo, webots

***Error:***

```
<PATH_TO_SUMO>/bin/netedit: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: ecs_SetReportErrorFunction
```

This error appears when I try to run netedit. I have both the Webots simulation software, as well as the SUMO simulation software in my system and both, have netedit. When I remove either one of the software and then run netedit, it works. So, I think the issue is because of the presence of netedit twice. I was running netedit directly from the terminal but even after I give the exact path of the netedit I want to run, in a python script, and then run that script(For eg: I give the path of the netedit in SUMO), it shows this error. How to force the system to use a particular netedit (either webots' or SUMO's) whenever the netedit command is given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a question of setting your environment variable(s) PATH (and possibly LD_LIBRARY_PATH) to the correct values. If you install SUMO via the package manager of your Linux (apt or something) there should be nothing to adapt. I see from the [Webots docs](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/automobile/sumo-exporter) that they recommend manual adaption of those paths. If you don't do those changes or revert them you should be always using the netedit coming with plain SUMO. If you want to use the Webots version adapt the paths such that they list Webots directories first.